# Semi-Dead Zone on Touch Screen On Droid 1

Tags: motorola-droid, touchscreen

I'm on a Droid 1 running [the latest build of GPA (15)](http://peteralfonso.com) and have recently had problems with my touch screen.

This issue started long after GPA15 was flashed, so I'm not blaming the ROM at all. It actually appears to be a hardware issue.

Here is the actual issue. When held portrait with the home/options/back buttons at the bottom, about an inch or so up from those buttons there is a "dead" strip that runs horizontally across the entire touch screen. Of course, the keyboard pops up under this strip.

So what do I mean by dead? Well, sometimes choosing an option/box/item that's in this zone, flat out isn't being registered. When typing, it actually causes the touch detection to go haywire. When I tap a key, it usually registers me tapping that key AND one or two of the surrounding keys. Sometimes it doesn't register the intended key just the surround keys.

So, pressing i might return i, might return ui, might return iu, might return u. This behavior happens with most of the keyboard and is incredibly frustrating.

On very rare occasions when I press a letter, it also registers me pressing a key on the completely otherside of the keyboard. The worst example of this is when i hit backspace and it's also registering 'c' and/or 'v' with the click.

As to further demonstrate the issue, I downloaded a drawing app (Draw! if any one's curious) and drew a bunch of lines. It works perfectly when drawing straight lines (well, I'm human so they aren't PERFECTLY straight) up and down, and left and right on the screen.. except when I get to the deadzone. When I'm drawing down (perpendicular) through the dead zone, it works fine with no abnormalities.

But when I draw in a parallel (left to right) direction, when i'm inside the zone it basically draws my straight line has harsh zig-zag lines (ever seen a heart rate monitor?). Additionally some spots in the zone won't be drawn on at all.

Another note to further show that it's a consistent hardware issue: this zone stays in the same place, no matter if I'm holding it portrait or landscape. I'm forced to type on my phone with it being held upside down so the deadzone doesn't go through my keyboard.

I know (well, pretty certain) this is a hardware issue and there's probably no real solution for this phone. But is there any documentation, known issues, reasoning behind this issue? It just started recently and I've had this phone (it's a 'like-new' replacement) for just over a year now.

Should I just bite the bullet and pay for the upgrade to Droid 3 next week?

Comment: If it's in a strip like that, it's probably a wire or two in the LCD connector going bad, making intermittent contact.  You could theoretically replace it; I'm assuming you don't have a warranty, so it's up to you whether paying to have it fixed is worth it.  Finding a replacement part on your own would probably be impossible.

Comment: Nope, it's not on warranty any more, but it's covered by carrier's insurance (asurion). However, Droid 1s aren't in production anymore, so I'm not sure what phone I'd get as a replacement. Ideas?

Comment: I ended up deciding to upgrade the phone to Droid 3 and I should get it by tuesday. Ugh it seems so far away. I also think my droid knows and is now exacting revenge on me as the situation I described above got worse and is now registering touches for no reason along that strip. It's hung up during calls several times already, and it's locking up selecting options on other menus because it's longpressing the option that falls inside the strip. Tuesay can't come soon enough...

Comment: Lots of people with moto phones seem to be having this problem. Moisture is a common theory. Not just dunking it or getting drenched in the rain but high humidity.