# Motorola Milestone is constantly firing touch events

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-milestone, touchscreen, bugs

Starting this morning, when I turn on my Motorola Milestones screen, it starts to constantly press random positions on the screen (starting applications, etc.) which makes it nearly impossible to use the phone. Most of the clicks are along the right side of the screen.

It started while I was reading an email.

Looks to me, like it is an hardware issue. But since I installed Cyanogen Mod 7 a month ago, maybe it could be related so some sort of touch sensitivity setting I don't know of yet?

Anyone experienced the same issues? Any idea how to solve it?

EDIT:

Seams like a Software issue.

- First I wiped the cache, dalvic cache and reset to factory defaults. But the issue stayed.
- Then I restored the last backup I had using Nandroid and now I have
  the exact opposite:

> The most right part of the screen is not touchable anymore.

At least that is better, than touching all the time. Still a little annoying.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I would also try re-flashing the ROM after doing a complete wipe in recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lengthy discussion about this on:

http://androidforums.com/droid-support-troubleshooting/87515-my-droids-touch-screen-going-crazy.html

The main point seems to relate to either oil and dirt covering the screen and/or heating up issues from dirt within internal components.

There are some suggested solutions such as carefully cleaning the screen and the speaker opening. It also seems to be strongly affected by moisture.

Comment: Water/sweat on *top* of the screen often caused problems like these for me. Switching off the display (standby) then wiping the screen thoroughly and switching it back on usually solved the problem however.

Comment: Heatening the phone with a hair dryer changed the behavior from sending touch events all the time to being not touchable on the right side. So I guess its moisture related. I now sent the device to Motorola. Hope they'll fix it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JochenJung no worries, best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently with my milestone 2. Unfortunately I had to send it to service. Now it works, but whole touch panel was replaced with a new one.

Just to clarify my problems: right column of touch panel (above search button, btw it didn't work as well) didn't work for more than one month. In more extreme weather conditions (temperature below 0 celcius) touch screen was pressed at random positions just like you have described.

Answer (score 1):

This seems similar to an issue I had this summer: I ended up having to get a new phone.

[Semi-Dead Zone on Touch Screen On Droid 1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11308/semi-dead-zone-on-touch-screen-on-droid-1)

Basically there was a horizontal bar worth of space on the screen that seemed to have random touches firing, and also in the same zone, it often wasn't registering my real touches. It was definitely a game of chance, and it was progressively getting worse. It got so bad I couldn't accept phone calls.

There was a comment on mine that suggested it was an electrical connection problem that could cause inconsistent contact -- which explains the spazzing out on my phone. This could very well be your problem, too.

I don't think it's a software issue. If you flashed a new image on there or restored a backup of before you started having issues and you're still having issues, that almost rules out software issue.

Though it's interesting that now you're having the opposite happen. But that's also similar to my problem, the fact that sometimes it'd go crazy with click misfires, and other times it'd be completely dead.

If it is indeed the same problem I had, unfortunately it's not really a user-servicable solution.. you're gonna have to either get a new phone or a warranty/insurance claim.

Good luck to you! Maybe all the issues people are having with their touch screens will convince the manufacturers to start using quality wiring. (Not really, but one can wish, right?)

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't sound like a software problem i'm afraid. Almost certainly hardware.

Your only choice really is to send it to the service center, as mentioned.

Sorry i couldn't be of more help.

P.S
Before sending it to the service center, put the stock rom back onto it!